# SSRA Matrix - Use subtotals for for further calculations

Tags: matrix, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have created a matrix report in SSRS and I'm trying to calculate the Marging per column (shown in red). Therefore, I need to use some aggregated numbers out of the report. For example, the COF Margin is calculated like this: COF / Average Loan. So, for costcenter 0002, it is -1400 / 1000000 = 0.14%. How can I achieve that for each column?
I also need to calculate the gross interest margin which is pretty much the same. Just Interest Income / Average Loan.
I can calculate the line in my SQL query, which I did in the past, but then the matrix adds up all the percentages in the very right total column, which is incorrect.
Any ideas?

[image: Example Matrix]

[image: Matrix SSRS]

Thanks,
Daniel

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "expose those values in your dataset"? You mean that I need to have an explicit column called COF and Average Loan? That's what I want to avoid since there can be more types over the time. So, I do not want to modify my query evertime a new types comes in. I basically want to tell SSRS to use the subtotals for interest income and Average Loan but I don't know how. Something like Fields!SubSubType="Interest Income"? How do I use this correctly?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to sum up the columns being averaged, and average the sums, like:

```
=SUM(COF) / SUM(AverageLoan)
```

Obviously that means you'll need to expose those values in your dataset if they aren't already there.

Comment: Hi TabAlleman,Thanks for you input. Where would I need to enter this expression? Do I have to add a child group under SubSubType and then use the expression in the column profitCentreCode? Thanks,

Comment: First of all it's not an exact expression, but it would go in the textbox that you want for the total COF Margin.   If you are already collecting the subtotals that you want to average on your report, you can look into using the ReportItems collection to get those values and average them.   I can't help much with details without sitting at your computer and playing with your report.  All I can do is give you the concept that you need to Average the Sums, not Sum the Averages.